# Make a window Static as well as allow adding text using CreateWindowEx()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using CreateWindowEx() function to create an "EDIT" window, i.e. where a user can type.

> g_hwndMain =  CreateWindowEx(0,
>                    WC_TEXT,
>                                NULL,
>                                WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
>                                0, 0, 400, 200,
>                                phwnd, NULL, 
>                  g_hInstance, NULL);

But I would also like the window to be static. Is there a way to do it during the creation of the window? Or any other function that may be used after the creation of the window? I tried using SetWindowPos function after creating the window using SWP_NOSENDCHANGING  and SWP_NOREPOSITION, but that didn't o the trick. ANy ideas?

---

No, I mean Immovable Window. Basically, the window I create should be able to accept text and be immovable at the same time.

Comment: By "static", do you mean read-only? Then send [EM_SETREADONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761655(VS.85).aspx) after loading the text.

Comment: By static he means that the window cannot be moved around.

Comment: But it's an edit control... unless you give it WS_CAPTION etc., you can't move it around anyway...?

Comment: You're right arul. BTW, I'm not a he :)
RichieHindle, the window is still movable with or without WS_CAPTION ( Unless it's declared "STATIC"). I was looking at whether I could use WC_TEXT and WC_STATIC at the same time, but I guess that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Ok So far I've done this to handle  WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message

```
BOOL OnWindowPosChanging(HWND hwnd, WINDOWPOS *pwp)
{

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK
WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uiMsg) {

        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, OnWindowPosChanging);
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and when I create my window, I do this:

```
g_hwndMain =  CreateWindowEx(0,
                            TEXT("EDIT"),
                            NULL, 
                            WS_BORDER,
                            0, 0, 400, 200,
                            phwnd, NULL, 
                            g_hInstance, NULL);

                    if (!g_hwndMain) {
                        RemoveImages(spHTMLDoc);//Just so I know that the window has been created properly
                    }
                    else{                           

                        SetWindowPos(g_hwndMain, HWND_TOP, 500, 500, 300, 300,  SWP_NOSENDCHANGING | SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
                    }
```

The SWP_NOMOVE flag does not let the *code* change the position of the window, but the user is still able to change the window's position by moving it using a mouse. But this is exactly what I want to prevent. The window should be *static*. Any thing missing in my code, or any more suggestions?

Comment: ok, I figured this out. In CreateWIndow, add WS_CHILD flag as the 4th param. THis will do the trick. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Better to use WS_POPUP instead of WS_CHILD

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632653(VS.85).aspx) message for that window and then set the `SWP_NOMOVE` flag of the flags member of the `WINDOWPOS` structure before you forward it along.

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/16/7123299.aspx) has an example (though he's preventing size changes, the technique is the same).